# With emacs, how to go to the pairing (balancing) parentheses

Tags: emacs

When cursor on one parentheses, how to jump to the pairing parentheses. Good to work in **emacs -nw** .

Just like **%** in Vim.

;;After got hint from @Lindy, @Francesco, I found more:

```
  C-M-f     Move forward over a balanced expression
  C-M-b     Move backward over a balanced expression
  C-M-k     Kill balanced expression forward
  C-M-SPC   put the mark at the end of the sexp.
  C-M-n  Move forward over a parenthetical group 
  C-M-p  Move backward over a parenthetical group 
  ;; C-M key binding can also be done by --> ESC Control-key

  ;;And put this to .emacs, it will highlight opening/closing parens:
  (show-paren-mode 1)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Matching braces in Emacs](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8627725/1225607)

Comment: there is also great `paredit` mode that keeps parentheses balanced, and allows to manipulate...

Comment: Hint: try `C-M-u` to go up to the surrounding paren before `C-M-f`, so you don't have to be on it already.

Comment: @AlexOtt hope you've become acquainted with SmartParens now, it's an improved/extended Paredit.

Comment: Regarding parenthetical movement broadly, check out [evil-lisp-state (Github)](https://github.com/syl20bnr/evil-lisp-state) if you're evil.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Use `C-M-right` and `C-M-left` (respectively `backward-sexp` and `forward-sexp`) to go to the beginning or the end of the current expression. This works for parenthesis pairs but also for plain words.

Comment: Thanks, I found it map to **switch desktop right/left** by my desktop.

Comment: Who can tell the command name of **C-M-right**? It's now bring me to other workspace by **gnome desktop**

Comment: @Andrew_1510 It's `backward-sexp`/`forward-sexp`. Instead of holding simultaneously Ctrl+Alt+<arrow>, you can produce these key bindings using `Esc` then `C-<arrow>`. This way, the key combination won't be captured by gnome and will correctly be forwarded to emacs.

Comment: You can also use `C-M-f` and `C-M-b` for forward and backward. (This corresponds to the `C-f` and `C-b` key mappings for plain forward and backward movement that predates keyboards with arrow keys.)

Comment: You should probably unbind them from Gnome if you don't use that functionality that often.

Comment: @Francesco: thanks a *lot* for this ESC thinggy to prevent conflicts, I never knew about it (despite being a Gnome / Emacs user since, well, Gnome exist ; )   Going to +1 one your answer so that you gain some SO rep !

Comment: Most DE already bind C-M-arrow keys for window or desktop movement. I recommend C-M-f and C-M-b which do the same trick and are likely to be DE-bound free.

Answer (score 33):

As mentioned in emacs wiki (http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/NavigatingParentheses):

- **C-M-n** forward-list Move forward over a parenthetical group
- **C-M-p** backward-list Move backward over a parenthetical group
- **C-M-f** forward-sexp Move forward over a balanced expression
- **C-M-b** backward-sexp Move backward over a balanced expression
- **C-M-k** kill-sexp Kill balanced expression forward
- **C-M-SPC** mark-sexp Put the mark at the end of the sexp.

https://superuser.com/questions/677516/how-do-i-jump-to-the-opening-or-closing-paren-brace-in-emacs

Answer (score 24):

For parentheses, braces and brackets just **double clicking** on them does the trick.

Comment: clicking? with your mouse? in emacs?

Comment: Clicking? In emacs? Bah, I say! :) -- *(I'm assuming the OP's not using xemacs?)*

Comment: Sometimes it is faster just to click something than to search for it or move the cursor position. FWIW, *double clicking* on some parens, bracket or curly braces will move the cursor to the its pair and select the inner contents. As of Emacs 24 on X, at least.

Comment: Nice! It works but only if you double click the open brace. It doesn't work if you click on the close to find the open (`backward-sexp` equivalent).

Comment: Why would anyone double-click when they can just do **C-s ( Left C-Space C-M-Right**?

Comment: @Felipe in Emacs26 you can double click on the close bracket to select the inner contents. Although I find clicking in Emacs blasphemy

Comment: Mouse causes RSI.

Answer (score 9):

I suggest <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>, as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>right</kbd>/<kbd>left</kbd> are already bound to my DE (switch to desktop on the right / left).

Answer (score 5):

I use the following small function for exactly that (though I don't know whether or not it matches vim's behavior; I'm no vim user myself):

```
(defun mo-match-paren (arg)
  "Go to the matching parenthesis."
  (interactive "p")
  (cond ((looking-at "\\s\(") (forward-list 1) (backward-char 1))
        ((looking-at "\\s\)") (forward-char 1) (backward-list 1))
        (t (self-insert-command (or arg 1)))))
```

Comment: This looks like it wants to be bound to '%' as it will insert the key pressed if it is not on a paren

Answer (score 5):

I would highly recommend [SmartParens](https://github.com/Fuco1/smartparens/) it has extensive navigation and manipulation of parenthetical structures (ie. wrapping, quotes, tags, brackets, braces, regular parentheses, sexp, etc.) With support for many languages, and structures, with easy customization.

It also supports fairly complex structures, which are referred to as [hybrid-s-expressions in its documentation](https://github.com/Fuco1/smartparens/wiki/Hybrid-S-expressions). Which makes it extremely powerful for manipulating code in languages such as C/C++, Java, JS etc.

For [navigation](https://github.com/Fuco1/smartparens/wiki/Working-with-expressions#navigation-functions) the following are used.

```
sp-forward-sexp (&optional arg)                 ;; C-M-f
sp-backward-sexp (&optional arg)                ;; C-M-b
sp-down-sexp (&optional arg)                    ;; C-M-d
sp-backward-down-sexp (&optional arg)           ;; C-M-a
sp-up-sexp (&optional arg)                      ;; C-M-e
sp-backward-up-sexp (&optional arg)             ;; C-M-u
sp-next-sexp (&optional arg)                    ;; C-M-n
sp-previous-sexp (&optional arg)                ;; C-M-p
sp-beginning-of-sexp (&optional arg)            ;; C-S-d
sp-end-of-sexp (&optional arg)                  ;; C-S-a
sp-beginning-of-next-sexp (&optional arg)       ;; none
sp-beginning-of-previous-sexp (&optional arg)   ;; none
sp-end-of-next-sexp (&optional arg)             ;; none
sp-end-of-previous-sexp (&optional arg)         ;; none
```

Note that it maps many to commands to the Emacs default equivalent. When it's installed, just browse its functions (they're all prefixed with `sp-`) to get a good feeling for its scale.

There's a lot more to it, I'd recommend you have a [look at the wiki](https://github.com/Fuco1/smartparens/wiki)